# Where does kubectl store its logs?

Tags: kubectl

I'm trying to locate any logs that kubectl may store related to errors raised locally in the process of executing kubectl commands. I can't find any documentation of where logs for the CLI itself may be stored, nor have I been successful in locating relevant code in the source.

I have tried looking in the usual paths for kubectl log folders (`/var/logs` etc) and searching the source code for anything related to local logging. I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

kubectl is a command and doesn't create any logs for itself!

If you want to view logs of pods you can always use `kubectl logs <pod-name>`

I will update my answer if you describe more precisely which logs you need!

Comment: I understand that kubectl is a command, many command line utilities will at least log errors and other messages generated by the process to stdout or a file somewhere.

Comment: @ErikPeterson I am sorry but kubectl for itself doesn't write any log files!